# Can we have multiple modules in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to create more than one module in angularjs for a single registration form?

Need some examples for demonstration.

Now can we two different modules?? One for the form validations and other to call a servlet post method. Because either of them is running. I want both of them to run simultaneously. How can I solve this issue? Please provide the html syntax to call both of the modules simultaneously.

Thank-you.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'servlet url'
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.person = data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        });
};  

var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);
validationApp.controller('MainController', function($scope){

    $scope.submit = function(){
        $scope.submitted = true;
      }
});
```

Comment: @Xakku where do you get that concept from?  If you mean one module that serves as the application root, then yes, use one module for that purpose.  However, logical business areas of your app SHOULD be grouped into modules.  It promotes cleanliness and allows you to load only what you need where you need it.

Comment: Anything is possible.  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, could you be more specific?

Comment: @JAL Updated my question. Please review.

Comment: @zsherman review the code.

Comment: Is it your intention to have two different angular applications on one page?Or are you trying to make myApp use validationApp? The question still isn't quite clear.

Comment: @zsherman i am trying to make two different controllers on one page. One for the registration of the form and other for calling the servlet using post. Correct my code if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

So say you have a module, 'registrationForm' in angular, but you want to split it's functionality down into two (or more) sub-modules. You can do the following:

```
    // first sub module
    angular.module('subModule1', []);
    // second sub module
    angular.module('subModule2', []);

    // main module for the registration form
    angular.module('registrationForm', ['subModule1', 'subModule2']);
```

So all you are doing here is injecting your sub modules into your main module, the same way you do with angular's own modules.
In this case, subModules 1 & 2 should probably be services. That way in registrationForm you can use the functions that they provide.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, it is easy to declare multiple modules. Just store them in separate variables.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
var myApp2 = angular.module('myApp2', [])
```